# Stochastic seismic inversion

Tags: geophysics, inversion, seismic, software

Could anyone recommend a free and reliable software capable of Stochastic seismic inversion for my project? am aware that Petrel is capable of Genetic inversion based on a non-linear multi-trace approach but i have no clue what that is about, I prefer stochastic method because it is more reliable. Any help?

Comment: Madagascar with SCons should be able to do what you want. With a SCons workflow, it's rather easy to incorporate your own code for stochastic analyze or any statistic tools.

Comment: I'm interested in the answer to this too. There might be something in [this list of open source software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_free_geophysics_software).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, initially I was thinking of a simpler tool in which I would just have to click and click and it would get the work done, but this approach sounds better it will enable me to understand the nitty gritty of the process, could you please give me a breakdown of how to get started and am a novice at inversion.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to investigate the Delivery package available from

http://www-old.dpr.csiro.au/StochasticSeismicInversion/

'Delivery is an open-source, trace-based Bayesian seismic inversion code for use in oil reservoir characterisation at the early development and appraisal stage. See the Computers and Geosciences paper for most of the details, and the Delivery4D preliminary writeup for the time-lapse modelling.'

Comment: Direct link to the Computers and Geoscience (2004) paper is here:
http://www-old.dpr.csiro.au/StochasticSeismicInversion/DeliveryPaper.pdf

Comment: While I've never tried Delivery myself, I'm told that setting it up is rather tricky. You could try using DUG Insight, which has a GUI tool to set up Delivery runs. You can get a 30 day trial license fairly easily from www.dugeo.com. Be sneaky and keep the scripts that are generated for further use. Or if you're a student you may be able to ask for a full license.